# How can I use PyInstaller to convert a python script which also import side script or packages

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, exe, converters

I have to convert my python script to an EXE file. For this purpose I decided to use PyInstaller but I don't have a complete experince of it. When I ran the "-onefile" option to generate the exe, I see that exe file is not displaying the PyQt GUI at all. I ran this: `pyinstaller --onefile converter_GUI.py`

In my warnings log I see the following warnings:

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (delayed, optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), subprocess (delayed, conditional, optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (delayed, optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), subprocess (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named fcntl - imported by subprocess (optional)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional), importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), test.support (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional)
missing module named org - imported by copy (optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
missing module named pep517 - imported by importlib.metadata (delayed)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by C:\Users\cante\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py (top-level)
missing module named msys_writer - imported by C:\Users\cante\OneDrive\Desktop\plan-conversion\converter_GUI.py (top-level)
missing module named dxfParser - imported by C:\Users\cante\OneDrive\Desktop\plan-conversion\converter_GUI.py (top-level)
missing module named mechanism - imported by C:\Users\cante\OneDrive\Desktop\plan-conversion\converter_GUI.py (top-level)
```

Do I need to use hooks or other options? I need your help with this, what command should I to use?

My project structure is as follows:

- Converter [FOLDER]

  - EZDXF [SYSTEM LIBRARY]
  - factory [FOLDER]
  - svgwrite [FOLDER]
  - converter_GUI.py [main is also here]
  - parser.py
  - mechasnism.py
  - writer.py

Thank you very much

Comment: Dos the exe error out? Are there any warnings about missing hooks when running `pyinstaller --onefile converter_GUI.py`?

Comment: This should be sufficient as pyinstaller keeps track of all imports.

Comment: @It_is_Chris I added the warnings log file to the post

Comment: Had to remove git related folders and now the command runs successfully.